# Создание Docker-образа с установленным из бинарника Node.js

Tags: node.js, docker

В процессе изучения Docker в учебных целях хочу создать Docker-образ с установленным из бинарников Node.js. Для этого я создал следующий Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN mkdir -p /opt \
  && wget -c https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64.tar.gz -O - | tar -xvz -C /opt --strip-components 1 \
  && ln -s /opt/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node \
  && ln -s /opt/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm \
  && ln -s /opt/bin/npx /usr/local/bin/npx
```

Образ создаю на основе alpine, скачиваю бинарники Node.js, распаковываю в папку opt, создаю ссылку в usr/local/bin, собираю, запускаю контейнер и  проверяю, что Node.js установлен:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm <container_name> node -v
```

Однако получаю ошибку:
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory". Если тоже самое сделать на хост-машине, то Node.js устанавливается. Что не правильно я делаю? Что нужно сделать, чтобы создать образ Docker с установленным из бинарников Node.js?

Comment: посмотрите [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/daa131d713cf42ae181292471766879f750b5230/8/alpine/Dockerfile) для node/alpine и сравните со своим

Answer (score 0):

> Что не правильно я делаю?

Если Вы пытаетесь запустить бинарник node в alpine, то вам также потребуется доустановить в Docker-образ необходимое окружение. Чтобы посмотреть "потребности" бинарника, можно воспользоваться командой `ldd`

```
sudo docker run -it --rm <container_name> sh
cd /opt/bin
ldd node
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fa11bdc1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fa11bdc1000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fa11bdc1000)
Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by node)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fa11bdc1000)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by node)
```

> Что нужно сделать, чтобы создать образ Docker с установленным из бинарников Node.js?

Вариант 1

Прописать в Dockerfile установку окружения для nodejs: `libgcc libstdc++` и прочее.

Вариант 2

Установить nodejs через apk

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.8
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
```

Проверяем

```
sudo docker run -it --rm <container_name> node -v
v8.14.0
```

Вариант 3

Используем стандартный образ

```
docker run -it --rm node:lts-slim node -v
```

В Dockerfile для своего приложения можете использовать этот образ как базовый

```
FROM node:lts-slim
RUN ...
COPY ...
```